# Code for cookie handling from FB documentation not working

Tags: facebook, api, cookies

there's a code sample in FB's documentation for retrieving the user's cookie [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/). It's the last code sample right at the bottom of that page:

> The JavaScript SDK saves the details for the logged in user in a cookie named fbs_YOUR_APP_ID. The following PHP example shows you how to use access this cookie and then customize the generated page based on this information: [...]

When I simply copy that code into a new file and fill in my app ID and my app secret, I receive the following error message:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in [...] at line 26

Line 26 would be the last line of the following three lines:

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
    $cookie['access_token']));
```

I'm a little lost right know. Any ideas?!

Comment: Can you show us what the error message Facebook gives you except for the error code?

Comment: There's nothing but the login button and this error message! (Or am I getting something wrong?)

Comment: The 400 error is returned by Facebooks Graph API. And with that error code there is an error message explaining what went wrong with your request. So for us to being able to help you, you need to find out what that error message is.

Comment: What I would like to do first is to check the value of $cookie['access_token']

And make sure that is a valid value and not an empty string. This is my first assumption since a 400 error means the server thinks your request was malformed.

Comment: Ah, well, yes, $cookie['access_token'] is empty, but that should be alright as long as I'm not logged in with FB. However, when I click on the login button, FB will give me a not really informative "An error occurred. Please try again later." - Googled that already one, but didn't find anything about it.

Comment: OMG, I'm so sorry for taking your time, Ancide and Jason. I confused the app ID and the app secret. The code sample does work. This is definitely embarrassing.